# Php loop and count through txt file

Tags: php, file, count

I got a bit of a complex problem. At work we have to count our inventory every month. This is done with a scanner. At each location there can be up to 100 different items. Every item, even the same kind have to be scanned. When each location has been scanned, we print out the list of scanned items. The problem is that each scan has its own line in the txt file (it done not add/subtract multiple counts of the same item)

As the vendor of our system is notoriously slow implementing new functions I thought about a php script that does the following:

- **1:** read every line from the txt file
- **2:** add/substract the count of the same item
- **3:** print out a list with the item number and count.

The txt file is as following:

```
01234+000001N
```

Where the first 5 digits is the item number. As it is possible to add and substract the next symbol is + or - then the next 5 digits is the count and the N is the "eol"

So somehow I have to put it all in some sort of array and the sort it by item number. And the add/substract and then finally print out the final list

Comment: I think You really want a database inventory system. Every item your company sells can have a database row and these things can be automatically marked accordingly, sold, retained, whatever.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump musings or to-do lists.

Comment: As you are scanning items that exist, why would there ever be a `-`?

Comment: As users are involved there can be situations where they scan an item to much. The scanner accept that the user can substract that scanned item :-)

Comment: Marc B: I know this is not an to do list, I'm just "brainstorming" with this great community :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've loaded the file into a string, line by line, and is split by a new line, you can do the following; (read code comments)

```
$strTxtFile = <<<TXT
01234+000001N
01234+000001N
09876+000002N
01234+000001N
01234+000001N
09876+000002N
01234-000001N
09876+000002N
TXT;

/**
 * 01234 should have 3 stock
 * 09876 should have 6 stock
 */

$arrProducts = array();
$arrFileLines = explode(PHP_EOL, $strTxtFile);
foreach($arrFileLines as $strFileLine) {
    //Split the lines by the action (+/-)
    $arrStockAction = preg_split("/(\+|\-)/", $strFileLine, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    $strProductCode = $arrStockAction[0]; //The first part is the product code
    $strAction = $arrStockAction[1]; //The action (+/-) to the stock
    $intStockAmount = (int) $arrStockAction[2]; //Cast it to an int to get the number

    //Check if the product exists in our array, if not, create it with 0 stock
    if( array_key_exists($strProductCode, $arrProducts) === FALSE ) {
        $arrProducts[$strProductCode] = 0;
    } 

    if($strAction === "+") {
        //Add stock
        $arrProducts[$strProductCode] += $intStockAmount;
    } else {
        //Minus stock
        $arrProducts[$strProductCode] -= $intStockAmount;
    }
}

print_r($arrProducts);
```

https://repl.it/ECrW

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, maybe a little simpler:

```
foreach(file('/path/to/file.txt') as $line) {
    $item = substr($line, 0, 5);
    $sign = substr($line, 5, 1);
    $qty  = substr($line, 6, 6);

    if(!isset($result[$item])) {
        $result[$item] = $qty;
    } else {
        $result[$item] += $sign.$qty;
    }
}
```

Or replace the `substr()` lines with:

```
preg_match('/(\d{5})(.)(\d{6})/', $line, $matches);
```

And use `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]` and `$matches[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out I had misread the txt file. The lines is as follow:

01234000001 N

And

01234000001-N

The blank space between the last number and the N represent addition and - substract